# Confusion about "data-template-name" and "id" in "<script>" tag

Tags: ember.js

After `<script type="text/x-handlebars"`

a. I'm wondering in what cases do I put `data-template-name` and what cases do I put `id`.

In the [guide tutorial video source](https://github.com/tildeio/bloggr-client/blob/master/index.html#L26) they use `id`s exclusively.

In the [todomvc source](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/index.html) and pretty much everywhere else I've seen, `data-template-name` is used.

b. And what exactly is put after `data-template-name` and `id` (i.e. what comes after their `=`)?

Answer (score 2):

a) AFAIK `id` is the newer version of `data-template-name`, and they seem to work the same.

b) The `id` allows you to identify a template it in your routing, rendering or 'views'.

**For Routing:** 
You can use this name to help the router identify which template to render, e.g. use `this.render('displayStuff)` during the `renderTemplate` in a route, to "override" the default template that belongs to the route.

See also: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

**For Rendering:**
Templates allow specific ways to change rendering. Ember-Handlebars provides `{{render}}` and `{{partial}}` to change the default template associated to the view.

See also: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/

**For Views:**
By default, a view will find its corresponding template based on convention. So the `somethingView` has an associated `somethingController` and a `something` template (so template with `id='something'`). A view will also allow to forgo this convention by setting its `templateName` parameter.

See also: http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/

hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

- Both work and are correct but data-template-name has a higher precedence and gives you more freedom re: element id's (they wont conflict with template ids)
- via http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-components-id-or-data-template-name-in-handlebars-script-tag/3847
- also when you move your handlebars templates to stand alone files (production situation lets say) you won't need to worry about id vs data-template-name (let your build tools do this for you based on the template file name)